# Unitary representations of finite dimensional Lie groups on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unitary-representations, smoothness

I am interested in the proofs of continuity of some standard unitary representations appearing in Physics. Additionally, I am interested in the integration of finite-dimensional Lie algebras of skew-symmetric operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I know the theoretical results on the topic proved by Nelson, Simons and others. I think that I already know some standard works/references on the topic:

Unbounded Self-adjoint operators on Hilbert Space, K. Schmudgen

On the Integrability of Representations of Finite Dimensional Real Lie Algebras, J. Simon

Methods of modern mathematical physicsIV, Reed and Simon,

SELF-ADJOINT ALGEBRAS OF UNBOUNDED OPERATORS, R.T. Power

Spectral theory of families of self-adjoint operators, Y.S. Samoilenko

Although I know several criteria for integration of finite-dimensional Lie algebras of skew-symmetric operators, I am rather concerned with its practical applications. As far as I could check, it is frequently not trivial to prove it.

For instance, I look for a proof of whether the Lie algebra of skew-symmetric operators <$ip^2$, $ix^2$, $i(px+xp)$> on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ induces a unitary Lie group representation of SL(2,R) on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I managed to prove the continuity of the standard unitary representation of the Heisenberg Lie group by proving that the Lie algebra $<ix,ip,iI>$ admits a common basis of analytic vector fields. Nevertheless, I did not find an easy manner to prove the characterizations in terms of analytic vector fields for the standard Lie algebras of operators appearing in physics. I did not manage either to obtain that the expected associated representations are continuous.

Thank you in advance for any information.